# Building a custom linux (ubuntu) distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, distributions

I'm planning to build a custom ubuntu distro by removing unnecessary packages and installing only what i need and then rolling over the distro as an iso file and ready to be deployed. Can anybody suggest me a way on how can i do it?

Comment: only you get to define "necessary"

Answer (score 2):

For a more simple work, that is probably all what you want...
http://www.remastersys.org/

But if you are planning changing init system, and other internal things, start by learning everything about the linux boot process, partitions and initrd file, also some important kernel compilation aspects can help you to make better decisions. Shell Script is a requirement too in my opinion.

Good Lucky...